# How to disappear from the first page of search engines' search results?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking

I finished building my website a few days ago. I built it just for the purpose of having a presentable branding, and don't want people to contact me frequently. But now it's already appearing on the first page of Google's search results.

I don't plan to receive such a high exposure. But I also don't want to be removed completely from Google's search results.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent my website from appearing on the first page of search engines' search results.

Comment: If you don't want people contacting you from visiting your website, then just remove the contact information as well as any forms on your site that cause mail to be sent to you. If they still contact you, then get a new email address and/or phone number.

Comment: Are you appearing at the top of SERPs for your brand name? If you have an original brand name that's also not a competitive term, you'll be at the top of search results for that keyword. Otherwise, you can work to either take your website out of SERPs altogether, or let it be as is and let it rank as it will. There's no way to say to search engines, "Rank me a little bit, but not too much, maybe on page 2 or 3." I think @Mike provided the optimal solution here.

Comment: @HenryVisotski Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite! I'd say it's an answer but @Mike provided the solution.

Comment: First person ever to want a worse SEO rank

Comment: Nice problem to have! Take advantage of it and don't kill your SEO. There's plenty of us out there to envy you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a site is new, little is known about it. Google likes to test new pages and sites with higher positions for a period. There are two thoughts on the subject. One is that any good site should enjoy testing for a period instead of falling to the bottom of the SERPs and never being able to compete. The other thought is that while a sites metrics are being built, and this takes quite a bit of time, any site should be given some grace.

All sites will perform well for a period. That is well known. However, as a sites metrics are gathered in the index and SERP performance metrics are gathered, SERP placement begins to change to something more appropriate.

Another consideration is how the site performs in the SERPs for specific search queries. Any site will vary in how it can be found by specific search queries. Since about 15% of search queries are new and have never been seen before, that vast majority of search queries are well known and sites that perform well for these queries are well established and difficult to compete against. It may be that your site will perform well. As well, it may be that your site will not perform well. Time will tell.

So while your new site is performing well today, that may be only for a period and for select queries to be adjusted over time. If branding is what your goal is, I suggest focusing on that. This answer [How do you get Google to show wiki information about your site in the right side bar of the search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99933/how-do-you-get-google-to-show-wiki-information-about-your-site-in-the-right-side/99953#99953) talks about some of the steps in branding.