# Are Google business listings relevant for website businesses?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-my-business

I want to help google produce for my site, the right side infobox it shows on some results (with logo, social profiles etc.).

I believe this info is taken from various places, but the main one is the Google business listings.

Is there a point (or even allowed) to create a Google Business listing for a website based brand/business, like being a blogger or a niche portal?

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about a business without a physical storefront, correct?

Comment: Google My Business AKA (Google Local) is for Local and national Businesses, not Local Bloggers, so if you do not serve the customer at their home or at your store front then you do not qualify for Google My business.

Comment: Yes, a business without physical storefront. Lately Google business expanded into businesses without a storefront (https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038163). Still I'm not sure if a money-making site or blog qualifies for a Google business listing.

@Simon I wonder why they removed the "local" from their name. Though you are probably right.

Comment: Does this question help? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99933/how-do-you-get-google-to-show-wiki-information-about-your-site-in-the-right-side