# How to get cart data showing up in google chrome blank 'new tab'

Tags: seo, google, schema.org, google-chrome

I've been seeing that this is somewhat of a new feature but I have just experienced it myself for the first time

[image]

Do I need to have a certain schema for my cart/checkout page?

I'm not sure what the criteria is for this to show up as the docs seem to only reference users and not developers

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/11032183?hl=en

for example, my question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99933/how-do-you-get-google-to-show-wiki-information-about-your-site-in-the-right-side) I was able to obtain a knowledge card by adding schema.org and having a wiki page essentially, I'm wondering what the next step is to achieve this for the new tab page

Comment: Is it not obvious to you that this is a browser feature ?

Comment: Obviously it is, but obviously there is criteria to get there @RohitGupta so please enlighten me